# SQL Custom Replication Via Triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logging

As I have seen, SQL 2008 no longer offers replication over internet in very simple method. Not only that, I can see that the merge replication method installs too many triggers and views onto database and adds additional field named "rowguid".

We have more disc space available today then the processor speed. So I decided to write my own generic Replication for SQL Server. It requires following steps.

This has an assumption that all my tables have one single primary key (either bigint or nvarchar(50))

```
Setup Table : SyncItems
SyncItemID  (Primary,AutoNumber)
SyncTable (nvarchar(50) name of table)
RowID (bigint)
RowIDStr (nvarchar(50))
RowOp (nvarchar(10), 'Inserted','Updated','Deleted')
RowTime (datetime, current_timestamp)
```

And I can setup three triggers on each of tables of database, which can insert one item in SyncItems for specifying DML.

Now all replicators, can only first scan through SyncItems and load the modified table row and update at the destination.

**Question:**

1. I already have setup Database Recovery model to full. Is there any alternative method where I can read DMLs history and replicate rather then setting up triggers?
2. How long the history of transaction logs are kept? In the trigger based custom replication, I can delete older records and we can truncate table accordingly.
3. If I can read transaction logs and replicate manually, that will be great because we can even replicate DDL transactions. I tried using searching for various stored procedures and did enough Googling but didn't find any hint.
4. Is there any option to read replication publisher logs? So that instead of using SQL Server's own replication, we can write our own replication agent which can replicate data over internet?

(I have tried web sync, and various options, but our data is huge, and its not practical to use web sync)

Comment: From what I read here, it seems you are under the assumption that only one row at a time will be processed in a trigger. Make sure your triggers can handle multirow inserts, updates, deletes.

Comment: Yes they can handle multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any option to read SQL Logs. However, in full recovery mode SQL does store entire transaction logs into SQL logs, but there is no documented way to read that. We continued writing our own replication method by using triggers to fill in SyncItems table !!

Answer (score 0):

Won't it be easier to use change data capture if you are using SQL Server 2008 EE ?

I am using it to load a different database to analyze changes in the data over time, seems to work fine.

Comment: We have SQL 2008 Standard Edition only, and we cant upgrade because the cost is too high, and we are using Standard edition to store user documents, so they are big in size, but also important to store on database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered log shipping?  It may do what you want more simply and with a little work you can make it work over the internet.

Comment: Log shipping does not work over internet, everything works over local area network only. If i can read logs and rebuild by myself that would be great !!

Comment: It is true that log shipping was not designed to work over the internet, but there are ways of making it work.  The most direct one of course is to set up a proper vpn and let windows see the whole thing as one domain, but if you are willing to write your own scripts for certain parts it can be done.